# How to give body padding to extjs4 promt? rendering issue with prompt in ie7 and firefox?

Tags: extjs4

I am using simple extjs prompt for getting one value from user

```
Ext.Msg.prompt('Name', 'Please enter your name:', function(btn, text){
if (btn == 'ok'){
    // process text value and close...
}});
```

In chrome it is rendering correctly, but in ie7 and Firefox, the text-box stretches completely without any padding. so that i cant see left & right side of the text-box.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **IE7** copy this code into your HTML file: (`<head> Tag`)

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<style type="text/css">
        .x-window-body-default .x-form-text {
                width: 215px !important;
        }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

We don't have this problem in FireFox. Which version of FireFox are you using? If you are using the older versions, you can use `<style>` above that only targets FireFox with help of the link below depending on your version:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-hacks-targeting-firefox/